# How to replace the image running in Amazon ECS with a newer docker image automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a docker image running in Amazon ECS (Amazon EC2 Container Registry). The docker image path is defined in task definition.

Now after I make edits to my code, Jenkins automatically build the new image and pushes it to the Amazon repository registry and I get a new PATH based on the build number.

The new URL is like

```
1234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/csr:13
```

The old URL is like

```
1234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/csr:12
```

Now I want that **Jenkins run some command in CLI** to tell ECS that there is a new image that it should run on the EC2 instance instead of old.

I was reading [AWS CLI documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_AWSCLI.html#AWSCLI_run_task) and I came across commands like `aws ecs register-task-definition` and `aws ecs run-task` but I am not sure.

I am clueless how devops do this? What is the proper way? 
Please help.

A simple task definition looks like this:

```
{
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "taskRoleArn": null,
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "memory": 512,
            "extraHosts": [],
            "linuxParameters": {
                "capabilities": {
                    "add": null,
                    "drop": null
                },
                "devices": null,
                "initProcessEnabled": null
            },
            "dnsServers": [],
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "dnsSearchDomains": [],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 9000,
                    "containerPort": 9000,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                },
                {
                    "hostPort": 3306,
                    "containerPort": 3306,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                },
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                },
                {
                    "hostPort": 443,
                    "containerPort": 443,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "hostname": null,
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "name": "phpfpm-nginx",
            "ulimits": [],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "ERRORS",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "WEBROOT",
                    "value": "/data/www/public_html/"
                }
            ],
            "links": [],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": false,
            "image": "1234.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/csr:13",
            "command": [],
            "user": null,
            "dockerLabels": {},
            "logConfiguration": null,
            "cpu": 0,
            "privileged": false,
            "memoryReservation": null
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [],
    "family": "ecscompose-CSR",
    "placementConstraints": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is wondering same question as I was few minutes ago, 
I found an open source cli program called [ecs-deploy](https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy)

It pushes your new image to ECS easily.
I hope it helps someone in future.